# ComboBox drawn incorrectly for empty cell and scrolled on OSX

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Given a simple `wx.grid.Grid` and `wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor` as default cell editor. Now try scrolling down in the grid and start edit on an empty cell. Now, if the cell had a value, everything would be fine. However, when the cell is empty, the TextCtrl of the ComboBox is drawn in the wrong place. It seems like the vertical scroll offset is subtracted twice. [Source code for sample app](https://gist.github.com/4059634/ac3784ef3e30aa3cf9969f10661c34e3abb11886).

[image: Rendered correctly]

[image: Rendered incorrectly]

WX version 2.9.4.0

Comment: This looks like a bug in wxOSX. If it still exists in the latest svn, you should really report it using the [usual procedure](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I now set a non-empty value when the editor is about to be shown. Using a `wx.CallAfter` I set the value to empty again, so the user doesn't notice anything. However, the value in the grid will remain the non-empty value (space), as changing it in the callback will trigger an incorrect re-render.

```
def __init__(...):
    # ...
    self.grid1.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_EDITOR_CREATED, self.editor_created)
    self.grid1.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_EDITOR_SHOWN, self.editor_shown)

def editor_created(self, event):
    self.control = event.GetControl()
    event.Skip()

def editor_shown(self, event):
    cursor = event.Row, event.Col
    value = self.grid1.GetCellValue(*cursor)
    if not value:
        self.grid1.SetCellValue(cursor[0], cursor[1], ' ')
        def unfix():
            self.control.SetValue(value)
            self.control.Popup()
            # @todo should set the cell value back to empty value here,
            # but that triggers the bug again.
        wx.CallAfter(unfix)
    event.Skip()
```

And also [source code](https://gist.github.com/4059634/fb02f9edc6f08d29ac7e99eaf268e1ba3d6a0eeb) of a working example.